# React-Native app reverse engineering and obfuscation

Tags: apk, react-native, reverse-engineering, expo

Is react-native expo generated apk obfuscated?

```
exp build:android
```

How can I retrieve my react native JS source code back using that apk? Do I need dex to java compilers for this purpose?

Looking for your valuable suggestions as I am concerned about the security of my react native app and trying to compare obfuscated vs non-obfuscated code

Comment: The @Facebook development team has to answer this. #Facebook

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to decompile the app using dex to java tools.

If you generate a production build it will be minified, but this is far from being a high level obfuscation which you can try to achieve with [react-native-obfuscating-transformer](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/react-native-obfuscating-transformer)

You can find the js bundle by opening the apk with a zip archive manager. The bundle will be at:

`/assets/index.android.bundle`

In anycase, any client side code should be treat as unsafe, if you need security use your backend to handle it.

Comment: ok but how do we unobfuscate the js code?